# Is data integrity important when using Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord's associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm just playing with RoR and I've noticed that ActiveRecord associations such as `has_many` or `belongs_to` are decoupled from the database running behind, i.e., these association are set regardless of the the constraints set by the database. For example, I have a table `comments` and a table `users` and they are related through `has_many` and `belongs_to` statements (a comment belongs to a user and a user has many comments). However these associations still let me assign a comment to a, for example, non-existing user. The reason of this is that there's no foreign key defined in the database.

My question is: should I just rely on ActiveRecord's associations to handle data integrity or should I also add foreign keys in migration files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Rails holds some conventions that enforcement of data integrity should be done in the application, not in the database.

To keep data integer on application-level, you can use model validations to enforce the presence of associations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add foreign keys to migration file to make your associations work correctly. With reference to the example mentioned, you have to add an attribute user_id to comments table. For more information on how Active Record Associations work, follow this [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: Yeah, I know a user_id column should be added to comments table, but the foreign key should also be created in the database? The answer by @roman.brodetski below states that Rails conventions enforce data integrity to be done by the application, not by the database engine. What's your point of view?

Comment: No you don't have to create foreign key in the database. That is handled by Rails application itself. You don't have to perform any operation(database change) at the database level directly. To ensure data integrity, all the operations are to be performed at application level.